# jenkins performance plugin result file from remote server

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing

Is it possible to generate reports from remote result files?
I've tried many possibilities without any result, any help would be really appreciated :)

**What I've tried**

well I tried to ssh to my remote server and it didn't work, the official docs does not talk about remote results and it seems to me that the only way is to store the jmeter result file on server where jenkins is running.

i'm wondering if there is a way to do this remotely

Comment: show what you've tried ?

Comment: @Tej Thank you for your response, well i tried to ssh to my remote server and it didn't work, the official docs does not talk about remote results and it seems to me that the only way is to store the jmeter result file on server where jenkins is running. i'm wondering if there is a way to do this remotely ..
NB: sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: i've updated question as per your comment